# How do I make a bootable USB from Windows?

Tags: live-usb

I've downloaded the daily Ubuntu 12.04 iso.

I currently have windows 7 x64 operating system installed.

How can I make a bootable usb from the Ubuntu iso?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick-in-windows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make an Ubuntu live USB for installing Ubuntu in Windows, use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). Rufus is the recommended application at the official Ubuntu website for making a bootable live Ubuntu USB on Windows. The USB flash drive you use should be 2GB or larger and formatted to FAT32. For Ubuntu 18.04 and later the USB flash drive should be 4GB or larger. The formatting procedure will delete all of the files that are already on the flash drive.

The instructions for preparing an Ubuntu live USB are found at the official Ubuntu [How to create a bootable USB stick...](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) webpage (see the step-by-step instructions below).

1. Open Rufus and select your USB stick in the *Device* dropdown menu.

[image: IMG:]

2. Click the CD-ROM icon next to the *FreeDOS* dropdown menu, then find your downloaded Ubuntu ISO and click *Open* and then *Start*.

[image]

3. Click *Yes* when it asks to download Syslinux software.

[image]

4. Click *OK* to write in ISO Image mode.

[image]

5. Confirm that your USB stick is selected and then click *OK* to continue. It is **very important** to verify that the device that you are installing the Ubuntu live USB to is indeed your flash drive, so that you don't overwrite any of your system or personal files which may make your operating system unbootable.

[image]

6. When it is finished, just restart your computer and start using Ubuntu, or you can install Ubuntu.

[image]

The Ubuntu live USB flash drive that you make this way will be bootable from a PC. In order to enable your computer to boot from the USB flash drive, you must enter your BIOS menu by pressing one of these keys: <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> as soon as the motherboard splash screen appears when the computer is booting. In the BIOS menu, you need to change the boot order so that the USB flash drive, which is usually called USB-HDD in newer computers, is the first entry in the boot sequence, and then save your new BIOS settings and exit the BIOS setup.

Answer (score 8):

With UNetBootIN, for example. I like Pendrive Linux Easy USB Creator very much, but it doesn't support béta's without some tips 'n tricks. Testing an alpha isn't as simple as you think by the way, some experience is useful ;)

[Download for Windows](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/unetbootin-windows-latest.exe)

[image: Screenshot from unetbootin homepage]

Unetbootin is available for Windows, Mac, Linux (Lots of distros)

Comment: I've been testing ubuntu alpha's since 8.04. However I used CD's till now. There's a way of doing it through Virtualbox. I want to find a clean way. I tried Pendive Linux method. It didn't work. I'll try UNetBootIN. Thanks!

Comment: Virtualbox will boot the iso directly, no need to burn a CD or put it on a flash drive. unetbootin is a nice option, for additional options see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Comment: I use Yumi for any bootable USB creation since it supports multiple OS boot. https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Answer (score 2):

you can use **universal usb installer**
go to http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Universal-USB-Installer-Download-186578.html

install it

and then run it and select your linux version

and pendrive which is to be make as statup disk

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a nice way for normal iso's. However, the iso I'm trying is in alpha state. This method does not work for it.

Answer (score 1):

Open Unetbootin ...select daily_live ...that surely will boot.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu ISOs (since 11.10) are hybrid, they are both CD and USB bootable.
On Linux, you can just cat them to a flash drive.

On windows, follow the instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

### Windows 7

Right-click on an ISO image and choose 'Open with > Windows Disc Image Burner'.

[image]

Select a disk burner (drive) and choose 'Burn'. If you check 'Verify disc after burning', it will confirm that the ISO image has been burned correctly.

[image]

### Windows Vista / XP / Server

Download and install the appropriate version of [ISO Recorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm).
Insert an unformatted DVD into your burner. (Note: You can only burn DVDs with this tool from Vista.)

[image]

Open Windows Explorer, find your ISO file, right-click and choose 'Next'.

Answer (score 1):

Try Rufus. It's free and works better than unetbootin or live usb creator. It succeeded where both have failed for me.

Comment: agreed best out there

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen it mentioned, but [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxlive.org) is far and away the best I've tried. It's quick, easy, and allows Persistent Mode with no hassle. It is Windows-only, however.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using newer computer there is a good chance it support UEFI.

Now I understand this is an old post, but if someone have the same problem nowadays many of this answers just won't work. So if you want to create a bootable USB from Windows with all the new technologies supported (UEFI, GPT) you should use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).