# Dazzle DVC 80 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, video-capture-card

Can I use Dazzle Digital Video Creator (DVC) 80, a USB composite video capture device, on Ubuntu? It doesn't work in Windows Vista/7/8 only on XP but I don't want to install XP and I would like to use it in Ubuntu.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my Sony Vaio so if you know how to install it I would love some help.

Answer (score 0):

According [to this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biQ8FXxoXN8) this seems to work.

I'd create a [bootable USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-to-make-a-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-installer) and try it out.

Comment: The DVC 80 is a piece of hardware. I'm **not** suggesting to try anything with wine. Check the video I've linked.

Comment: The video doesn't load because of network routing issues on my end, I apologize for misunderstanding.