# Server Install from 1 Gig USB

Tags: installation

How can I install the Ubuntu CD ISO image on to a 1 Gig Thumb drive so that it can boot to my target system?

Thanks

Comment: The same way you'd do a desktop LiveUSB I imagine. What computer do you have access to at the moment which you can use to write the USB?

Comment: This depends on what system you have access to.  But instructions for creating a USB from Windows, Mac or Ubuntu are here [How to make a Ubuntu USB Flash Drive Installer?](http://askubuntu.com/q/287064/107450)

Answer (score 0):

Installing the server edition from USB is not different than installing the standard desktop from USB. Use Unetbootin to prepare your USB stick from the .iso and then just boot your system from USB and install as always.