# Booting Ubuntu 12.04.1 from a flash drive

Tags: system-installation

How can I properly boot Ubuntu 12.04.1 from a flash drive?

I've tried to boot it using poweriso and after it finished downloading amd64.tar.xz, it gets an error message about not being able download the necessary files. My internet connection was never interrupted.

I shut down the laptop and rebooted using <kbd>F12</kbd> to select boot from usb, I get an error message about missing boot manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows use the [**Universal USB Installer**](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). Else, you can use the unetbootin to get it properly:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```