# 14.04 LTS Trial fails on my Vista PC

Tags: mouse, 14.04, system-installation

Recently tried to test the live 14.04 LTS cd on my Vista machine. 13.10 runs properly. No problem. Mouse works as expected. 14.04 loads and opens the live session but the mouse no longer functions. The tab key and enter key also do not work. I have to shut down the PC to get out. Is this because 14.04 is set up for a touch screen. It's strange that 13.10 runs and 14.04 LTS locks up. The PC has 3.0 GB of ram and a 3 Gig AMD Athlon 64 dual core processor. It's running Vista Home Premium SP 2, 32 bit OS. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a USB flash drive? Ubuntu on a USB flash drive runs faster than Ubuntu on a DVD. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-an-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-installer-bootable-usb/451866#451866).

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the issue of the touchpad not working in a LiveUSB session of 14.04. To work around that I simply plugged in an USB mouse, and then it worked fine.

Does this help?