# Running Ubuntu within Windows?

Tags: windows-7, live-cd

I would like to know if it is possible to do the following:

I need to access data on a EX4 formatted external HDD that is used as a backup for our CAD server at work.  I read that there are programs you can download to view the files, but they seem to have a habit of corrupting the data and I wish to avoid that.

I would like to create an Ubuntu live CD and run Ubuntu from that within my normal Windows 7 startup on the rare occasions that I will need to access those files and possibly write them to my (or any other) Windows 7 PC.  It is my work computer, so I would rather not install Ubuntu on a partition or anything to alter it and having the flexibility to use the CD on any of our workstations is absolutely perfect.

I read that there is an option when you run the live CD to "test drive" Ubuntu, but I want to make sure before I travel down that road.  From what I gather I download the Ubuntu desktop installation file, burn it to a CD, and then just insert the CD and run the program as a trial to have the functionality without the install.

I guess I am seeking assurance that my theory is correct with this live CD thing.  I am totally new to Linux and Ubuntu (but I'm a fast learner), so please be gentle.  :)  Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make an Bootable Ubuntu USB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-an-bootable-ubuntu-usb) CD is too small to run Ubuntu live, so your two options are either Ubuntu live DVD (slow) or Ubuntu live USB (fast). Ubuntu live USB can have persistent file storage space so that you can also install apps on it and because it is running live it does not write any files to the computer's hard drive. The one thing a live DVD/USB cannot do is to run two operating systems on the same computer at the same time, like a virtual machine can.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. Live CD

   You could use the Live CD to do this, but each time you change something on the Ubuntu (like settings) it will be lost, which may get frustrating.

   It's up to you if you would be happy with this.
2. Install on USB

   It is possible to install onto a USB and use that - as it will have persistent changes.

   It uses [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), which you can install on Windows with downloads on [this page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

   Instead of creating a new hard drive, give it an existing hard drive - the USB stick. You will format this, etc, and can then set it to boot from your computer's BIOS.

   [This answer has more details](https://askubuntu.com/a/54388/186134) about how to do this.
3. Virtualbox

   This solution also uses virtualbox, but in a slightly different way.

   Virtualbox is designed to run an OS inside a computer - and it can run on Window, Mac and Linux. As I said above, you'll want the windows host binaries (an `exe` file).

   Then install Ubuntu on the Virtualbox. [The answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox) should help, but the basics are here:

   1. Install Virtualbox on your laptop and then download the Ubuntu ISO file.
   2. Click new and then give it a name and chose Linux then Ubuntu 32 / 64 bit depending on the ISO you went for.
   3. Give memory and create a new Hard Disk (dynamically allocated VDI probably). It needs to be at least 8GB + what you need to be able to use it.
   4. Finish and then click settings then storage then the + next to Controller: IDE and navigate to the ISO. Click system and then click the tick next to cd, and move it up to the top with the arrows.
   5. Click okay and then Start, and Ubuntu will boot.