# Need help regarding dd command on Ubuntu app for windows 10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, drive, dd

I installed Ubuntu app on Window 10 OS and trying to run dd command. But the dd command is not listing all drives present in system. 
I am not sure whether is it Ubuntu app limitation or something is missing in configuration. Please provide me inputs to resolve this issue.

Comment: *gasp* you never want to use a low-level disk io program like `dd` in an OS like Windows.

Comment: ***NEVER*** do this in WSL.  WSL is also NOT a complete Linux environment, so `dd` being used there is NOT going to work properly.  DO NOT use it in WSL!

Comment: It may be possible to run `dd` on mounted devices in WSL 2 which is scheduled to be released in April, 2020.

Answer (score 8):

You can't.

WSL is not a complete environment. Notably, it lacks a Linux kernel.

WSL is an abstraction layer that allows execution of 64-bit ELF binaries on Windows. It does not provide the traditional Linux device access.

This may change [somewhat with WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install), which is HyperV-based virtualization solution.

Answer (score 5):

### Ubuntu and Linux in general running in Windows

As already stated by in the answer by @vidarlo, WSL cannot do everything, that we are used to do in Ubuntu (or Linux in general). But it is a good tool, that provides several of the tools and functions, that we are used to from Ubuntu.

Another alternative, that also suffers from limitations due to the lack of a Linux kernel is the old [CygWin](https://cygwin.com/).

@vidarlo also mentioned a virtualization solution, that might improve the capability of the next generation of WSL.

There are already other (and general) virtualization solutions. Maybe the most common one for personal use is [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

If your computer has enough CPU 'horsepower' and enough memory (RAM), you can run the **real Ubuntu** live and/or install it in a virtual machine using VirtualBox.

### Alternatives to `dd` in Windows

You want to use `dd` in WSL. It makes me think that you want to **clone** from a hybrid iso file, `file.iso`, or maybe from some other kind of image file `file.img` **to a device**, for example a USB pendrive, a memory card, an SSD or a hard disk drive.

In this case you can use Windows tools for cloning,

- [Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager): a dedicated **cloning** tool
- [Rufus in **'dd-mode'**](https://rufus.ie/): **cloning** (default mode: extracting the files into a FAT32 file system)

---

If you want to do **other tasks, for example recovering data from a failing drive**, it may be a good idea to create a [persistent] live drive with Ubuntu, install **`ddrescue`** from the repository with the package `gddrescue` and maybe some other tools into it (for example [TestDisk and PhotoRec](https://cgsecurity.org)) and work from there.

Comment: As an alternative I would also recommend trying Cygwin's dd binary, it has worked perfectly for me and I still use it to backup disk and partition images.

Comment: @PanosKordis, Thanks for this tip :-) Please write an answer and describe how to identify the drives in Cygwin, and the command line to use, and I will upvote it. `dd` can be very useful, but risky. There is no 'safety belt' against writing to the wrong drive.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend giving [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)'s `dd` a try.

To find the path to the disk or partition to use as input, view the file `/proc/partitions`

```
$ cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name   win-mounts

    8     0 125034840 sda
    8     1    562176 sda1  
    8     2 124470272 sda2   C:\
    8    16 3907018583 sdb
    8    17    131072 sdb1
    8    18 3906885632 sdb2   D:\
```

first.

To backup the entire disk a Windows partition resides in (e.g. `sda2`) use a command line like this,

```
dd if=/dev/sda ...
```

`/dev/sda` for the entire disk instead of the partition `/dev/sda2`

Comment: +1; Thanks, I had not fantasy enough to try `dd` in Cygwin :-)