# Can't make a live USB using Linux subsystem

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, dd, powershell

I'm trying to install Linux-lite
Tried Rufus but uefi option didn't show up in boot sequence.
So I thought I would use the dd command using Linux bash on Windows.

Obviously `lsblk` doesn't work
So I got the physical-name from PowerShell

```
Get-CimInstance  Win32_DiskDrive | Select Caption,DeviceID,InterfaceType,Size | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceType -eq "USB"}
```

Output

```
Caption                         DeviceID           InterfaceType        Size
-------                         --------           -------------        ----
SanDisk Cruzer Blade USB Device \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 USB           15373048320
```

Which I tried in Linux terminal

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -I \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2
```

But I got this error

```
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open \.PHYSICALDRIVE2: No such file or directory
```

I'm stuck here and I don't know how to move forward with installation.

Comment: But I will say that this looks like a duplicate of "[Need help regarding dd command on Ubuntu app for windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188090/need-help-regarding-dd-command-on-ubuntu-app-for-windows-10)", even though that was written before WSL2 was available.

Comment: WSL is on topic y'all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a bootable Clonezilla USB that works?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477573/how-to-create-a-bootable-clonezilla-usb-that-works)