# How to Boot from CD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios, samsung

I want to Boot Ubuntu from a CD. I have installed the ISO file on a CD. I have changed looked at my Boot priority list in my BIOS settings and I don't think my CD is there because I called it Ubuntu. What is in my Boot priority list is:

1. SANTA CD: SlimtypeDVD A DS8A9SH
2. SANTA HDD: ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB
3. USB CD:
4. USB FDD:
5. HDD:
6. NETWORK:

I have disabled Fast BIOS Mode and enabled USB wakeup but my CD still doesn't show in the Boot priority.
I have a Samsung notebook with windows 7 currently installed on it. I would like to have a dual boot. Can anyone help? If there are any more details that you need please tell me.

Comment: The name Ubuntu wouldn't show up.  It would be the manufacturer of your CD drive.  It looks like it's there.

Comment: @Daniel My CD's manufacturer is Woolworths Worthit

Comment: @ThomasW. What CD Option? I just downloaded the ISO file and then copied it to my CD

Comment: Use `SANTA CD: SlimtypeDVD A DS8A9SH`

Comment: @BenWelch copied *what*?  The single ISO file?  Or did you burn the ISO image to the CD?  (Burning the image is different than just simply copying the .iso file to the CD)

Comment: @ThomasW I just tried copying the single iso file. Is that may mistake?

Comment: @BenWelch it probably is if you didn't actually write the image that's within the ISO to the disk.  Check my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make an Bootable Ubuntu USB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-an-bootable-ubuntu-usb) The accepted answer has a link to the official instructions for making an Ubuntu DVD at www.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We established that the issue was the user just wrote the .ISO file as a single file to the CD/DVD and did not burn the image.  This is why the answer is written this way.

An .ISO file is a file that contains a copy of the *image* of a disk.  To make an ISO work on USB, you have to burn the ISO to a CD drive.

If you did not burn the ISO, then you have a bad disk, and wasted a CD.

[Read this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Burning_from_Windows) to know how to correctly burn the ISO to a CD/DVD.