# I can't get the `cp` command to work

Tags: command-line, cp, coreutils

In the terminal, when I issue the `cp` command, it states:

```
The program 'cp' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install coreutils
```

But when I try to install it, I get the errors listed below:

```
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.19.0-25-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.19.0-25-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 245: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 255: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 269: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 149: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 149: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 149: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 149: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 294: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 149: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 173: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cp: not found
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc: 149: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc: cp: not found
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 127.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic with 127.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Is this a brand new install?  If so, try reinstalling again.  I don't know of a single variant of linux that doesn't have `cp` right out of the box.

Comment: Care to explain what you did to get this happening? ;-) (the solution probably will depend on it). Tried another kernel for instance?

Comment: Well you have broken overall system. You'll likely need to reinstall

Comment: show us the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: No. Its worked before in the past. i was attempting to install new applications and give the executable files admin privileges.

Comment: here's the output of echo $PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Answer (score 2):

This just shows that you or someone else (maliciously) tampered with the machine by deleting the cp command (or even the whole coreutils package). This doesn't happen through normal usage.

## What to do when *cp* is missing

1. Create a [live USB-stick](https://askubuntu.com/a/287068/1736) (you'll have to use another machine to do that)
2. Boot from that USB-stick
3. Back up your data to an external drive
4. Mount your root partition, e.g.:
   `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` (/dev/sda2 is just an example, here)
5. Copy the cp command of the live system to your root partition and reboot
   `sudo cp /bin/cp /mnt/bin/cp`
   `sudo umount /mnt && sudo shutdown -r now`

When you're logged back in, install or reinstall coreutils to make sure everything is in order.