# Can't boot Ubuntu from DVD, getting OUT OF RANGE error message

Tags: boot, windows-10, livedvd

I can not boot from the Ubuntu DVD. When I try to boot from the Ubuntu DVD I get an "OUT OF RANGE" error message. How can I make Ubuntu installation media from Windows 10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 10 with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi)

Answer (score 2):

#### How to burn a DVD on Windows 7/8/10

1. Right-click on an ISO image and choose *Burn disc image*.

   [image: Burn disc image]
2. Select a disc burner (drive) and choose *Burn*. If you check *Verify disc after burning*, it will confirm that the ISO image has been burned correctly

   [image: Select a disc burner and choose Burn]

---

This flowchart shows how to make a bootable USB for installing Ubuntu and troubleshoot problems booting Ubuntu from it.

[image: IMG:]

#### Flowchart link

[How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

---

#### How to make an Ubuntu USB on Ubuntu

[How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb/451866#451866)