# How can I create a bootable USB stick on an Apple Macbook

Tags: windows, live-usb, mac, portable

How do I create a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu using an Apple Macbook that can then be used on my Windows PC to replace it with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 27):

**New Method using Etcher**

1. Make sure you have a USB Stick with at least 4GB of free space.
2. Get your Ubuntu ISO [from here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download?_ga=2.260955661.1498466740.1514631806-1392587894.1511432655).
3. Open **Disk Utility** from **Applications > Utilities**
4. Select the USB stick and select **Erase** (This will remove all data stored on the USB drive)
5. Select the format: **MS-DOS (FAT)** and scheme: **GUID Partition Map**
6. Click `Erase`

   [image: Disk utility]
7. Download, install and open [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) (By default MacOS blocks running apps from unidentified developers. Follow [this tutorial](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=25443) if you are experiencing problems with this.)
8. Select image and navigate to the location you saved the Ubuntu ISO you have downloaded in step 2
9. Select the USB drive you have formatted in step 3-6.
10. Click `Flash`

    [image: Etcher interface]
11. Congratulations! You now have Ubuntu on a USB stick, bootable and ready to go!

**Old Method using UNetbootin (might still work)**

1. Make sure you have a USB Stick with at least 4GB of free space.
2. Download and install [UNetbootin USB installer](http://unetbootin.github.io/)
3. Download [The Ubuntu Desktop ISO of your choice](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
4. Launch UNetbootin and allow the osascript to make changes

   [image: authentication]
5. Select the <kbd>Diskimage</kbd> radio button and then click the <kbd>...</kbd> button

   [image: unetbootin interface]
6. Select the ubuntu ISO file you downloaded and click 'Open'

   [image: selecting iso file]
7. Then select your flash drive in the bottom row and click 'OK'
8. After Unetbootin finishes, click 'Exit' and now you have yourself an Ubuntu USB stick.

[Source](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

Comment: Does one need to format USB stick before doing this procedure?

Comment: @Eric No Unetbootin will format the drive for you.

Comment: You do not need to format the drive with Etcher, it flashes the ISO directly on it.

Comment: You cannot select "GUID Partition Map" anymore on Mac OS Catalina. Where is it?

Answer (score 15):

1) Find the file path to your USB drive with

```
diskutil list external
```

You're looking for /dev/disk**N**. It's probably /dev/disk2, but double check that the `NAME` and `SIZE` columns make sense. The `dd` command you're going to run later will effectively delete all data on the drive so don't get this wrong. If that command produces no output, your USB drive is probably not plugged in.

2) Unmount the device so you can overwrite it (change `N` to the number you got from the previous step)

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN
```

3) Use [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)#Master_boot_record_backup_and_restore) to copy the .iso image to the USB with

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/your/iso-file.iso of=/dev/diskN
```

That step will take a while. When it's finished you might get an error saying that the disk can't be read, you can click "Eject" and you're done; use your USB stick to boot Ubuntu. If you don't get that error, you should eject it with 4)

```
diskutil eject /dev/diskN
```

---

You can speed up the `dd` command by adding [`bs=1m`](https://serverfault.com/questions/650086/does-the-bs-option-in-dd-really-improve-the-speed) (if you get the `invalid number: ‘1m’` error [change "m" to an uppercase "M"](https://rendezvouswithpavan.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/dd-bs-illegal-numeric-value-error-on-mac-os-x/) (this can happen if you installed a newer version of [coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/))) and using [/dev/**r**diskN instead of /dev/diskN](https://superuser.com/questions/631592/why-is-dev-rdisk-about-20-times-faster-than-dev-disk-in-mac-os-x) (use `/dev/diskN` for the `diskutil` commands though). You can get dd to report progress with `status=progress`. This would all look like

```
sudo dd bs=1m status=progress if=ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/rdiskN
```

With my cheap USB 2.0 drive I get 3.6 MB/s (9 minutes) with these options vs 0.8 MB/s (40 minutes) without them.

Comment: This worked fine for me with 18.04 iso.  I was able to use the resultant usb to boot into it on a macbook.

Answer (score 6):

Format your USB stick in FAT32 then open a terminal and type

```
dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/path/of/mounted/usb
```

Substitute the strings after = signs with your real paths.

That's really quicker than other method!

Answer (score 1):

sudo dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/dev/disk3

where disk3 is your usb device.
You need to umount the usb device before performing this operation.

dd is a dangerous command and can erase your disk completely. of=/dev/diskx
this x should never be your internal disk. Make sure you have not put your internal disk after "of=/dev/"

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you can. Look for the correct tool to do this, like [unetbooting](https://unetbootin.github.io/). For more information about, how to create a bootable USB you can look at this:

[How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

And here: [How do I create a bootable flash drive for installing Windows?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/bciz),

And here: [How to create a Windows 10 installer USB drive from a Mac](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-installer-usb-drive-mac).

Comment: This is to create a windows sick tho but he want's a ubuntu stick.

Comment: Wrong understanding. I read "...upgrade a windows PC...", so, i though, "he wants to upgrade his windows 8 to windows 10", because no "Ubuntu" is mentioned. Just didn't catch the idea. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Yeh thats what i tought aswel thats why i commented it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
m.apple.disk.iso.create() {
        local iso="${1}" disk="${2}" # example -> /dev/disk6
        sudo dd if="${iso}" of="${disk}"
}
```

Example call:

```
m.apple.disk.iso.create ~/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso /dev/disk6
```

Comment: Can you explain how these command lines works?

Comment: @damadam Does it work?

Comment: I don't know, I can't test it

Comment: I don't see the point of making this one line bash function instead of just invoking `dd` as already [suggested by @MKay](https://askubuntu.com/a/801566)

Comment: if you have a bunch of usable code ... dd in one case and other commands other times. which is easier to remember? all of them or through a consistent api that will give you what you need? m.apple.disk.format. it has to be the latter, otherwise you wouldn't have found this answer by googling ;) now take it down.. or try use dd through your memory in one years time again! how would you take it down? in a note file? or by declaring that method above, which in this case was just that command. but your question is valid in this example alone. for all 2+ liners, it wouldn't. I am just consistent.