# Ubuntu not taking its first boot

Tags: system-installation

I have a fully clean 120GB SSD. When I install Ubuntu using a bootable pen drive, the installation seems to go fine and I'm prompted to restart and unplug the pen drive, but when the system restarts, it loads into BIOS screen (where we see all motherboard tweaks), not Ubuntu... It feels like the OS is not installed

The pendrive is clean, its made bootable using poweriso tool
The ssd is clean too

Please suggest as it's happening since a long time now

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "load into BIOS?" BIOS is a normal part of every boot, so it's unclear what you are trying to describe.

Comment: I mean to say that normally when you turn on the machine it loads the operating system that is installed on the machine, in my case the machine is loading into system bios and not detecting the installed os

Comment: Check the boot options at BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Its UEFI by default +gabrielagracia

Comment: Ok. So, you need to go to the boot menu, find where it says "Windows bootloader manager" or something like that and click or enter and select Ubuntu instead.

Comment: I checked the boot menu, it shows ubuntu there as 1) Ubuntu but why is it not booting??

Comment: I also cannot see anything displayed under boot prioirty options :(

Comment: Please give details of your hardware - what is the make and model of the device?

Comment: My desktop pc which is i5 8400 cpu, corsair 8gigs of ram 120gb of ssd just for operating system, 500gb of HDD for storage, everything is brand new just 3 months for its first birthday

Comment: Trying 18.04 LTS, but non Lts 18.10 is also facing the same problem

Comment: I also tried formatting the SSD when i load ubuntu (try option) and then i run the installer to install the OS, but its same, after installation completion the pc boots to boot screen (bios screen) i dont want to switch to other os, i love ubuntu and i want this to solve anyway i know i am doing something silly which is causing this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb)

Comment: @Ashieshloveslinux The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: I have added everything i know, i could make a video and send to someone who is interested in knowing more about the problem i am facing, i have tried and understand each comment above, but nothing worked, in this stackoverflow askubuntu i can only input texts to make someone understand, also anything technically failing into my system due to UBUNTU is in the background and that i cannot mention here as i dont know, anything you want to know you can ask using keywords i will update you with my comments @gunbert