# Trying to Create a Bootable USB Stick

Tags: live-usb

I am VERY green. My ex left Debian on my laptop and it's too complex for me so 
I want to install Ubuntu on it. But I can't even get Ubuntu installed on a USB.

Start Up Disk Creator sees my USB but the "Make Start Up Disk" button is not clickable.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on one laptop --thanks to a Linux MeetUp! But it won't let me burn an ISO file (like I know what I'm talking about). I see there are similar questions but the answers are overwhelming. There is no simple way to create a bootable USB?

Time to go to another Linux MeetUp (and be the only girl)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb) check the flowchart in karel's answer. Did you download an Ubuntu ISO to begin with?

Comment: I sometimes go through errors depending on tools I use for creating USB sticks... May I suggest you to try with another tool? For example give a try to Etcher (https://www.balena.io/etcher/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the Startup Disk Creator to work, you need a copy of an Ubuntu installation media. You can download one from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop . Choose either of the options - the first one is recommended if you're not sure what you're doing.

The "Download" button will get you a file with a `.iso` extension - save it somewhere, maybe in the `Downloads` directory (don't worry about the donation screen that comes up - if you do nothing, it'll just start download the ISO file, you don't actually need to pay for that).

Once the ISO file has downloaded, open Startup Disk Creator, and it should show you the ISO file that you just downloaded in the first table - just click it and and then the USB drive, then the "Make startup disk" button should light up.

If you don't see the ISO file listed, click on the button "Other..." and find the ISO file using the file browser.

Comment: I see the reason this wasn't working for me was that I had not let the entire ISO file download. It took a long time. I was too impatient.