# "low disk space on filesystem root" Ubuntu 18.04/Windows 10 partitioned

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I just put Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop recently. It came with Windows 10, and I installed Ubuntu alongside with it. It should have 400 GB, but it's saying I only have 175.3 MB of space left. I'm wondering if I partitioned it wrong.

Also, when I first tried to install gparted, it gave me a message about low disk space. I ran autoclean and autoremove, and then I was able to install it. This is what gparted shows for my partitions.

[image: gparted]

Comment: Seems you have mistake during partitioning process, you're supposed to assign the 400GB to `/` (Ubuntu's root directory), where now you only have 19.10 GB.

Comment: The 400GB is now detected as external partition, showed as `/dev/sda8` on your picture.

Comment: Is there a way to switch partitions, or would I be able to do that through a re-installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: Does the `/dev/sda8` partition contain any file ?

Comment: @Emmet sda8 have 7.6Gb used at screenshot

Comment: @LeonidMew Whoa you're right, didn't see that. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3):

First you need to run gparted from live cd/usb, cause it can't do anything with partition it running from, and all other mounted partitions.
[How to make bootable usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb), boot from it, choose "try without installing" in boot menu, then run `gparted`.

- make sda8 smaller and move to the right(close to end of disk)
- move sda7 to the right, placing it just before sda8
- now you have unallocated space to the right of sda6, expand it to
  that space and you'll get a lot of free space in Ubuntu

Note, backup important files/documents you have in Ubuntu
You using sda8 to store something, make it's size enough to store your data but much less then 400Gb, this size difference will go to ubuntu partition
You should follow instructions carefully, incorrect usage of `gparted` can corrupt your installed OS

Comment: You should also consider to choose another mountpoint for /dev/sda8. It now looks like an external filesystem being mounted on /media/ether..., but it is not.

Comment: By close to the end of the disk, do you mean not all the way or all the way to the end? Is it possible to do it through a fresh installation as well?

Comment: Not all the way to the end but close to partitions in the right. You can do fresh install, but why, just moving/expanding partitions is easy, new experience. Everyone can do fresh install :) Anyway if you choose fresh install, first ask how to do it not harming your windows installation, and not loose important documents.

Comment: Gotcha. I want to try it the first way, I was asking in case I screwed up a second time.