# Ubuntu cannot upgrade via terminal nor the sofware updater applications

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, updates, 16.10

I tried

```
sudo apt update
```

And got the error:

```
$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                   
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                    
Ign:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                    
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu yakkety Release
  404  Not Found
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease  
Ign:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease
Ign:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-proposed InRelease
Err:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:12 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:13 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-proposed Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-proposed Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So, I tried this:

[Getting following error after the commad sudo apt-get update on Ubuntu 16.04 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244349/) but it didn't work. Then I tried [Multiple issues with "sudo apt-get update" - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358025)

Which now means I get this, when I try a dist upgrade from 16 to 18, via the Software Updater tool (silver circle icon): [Getting following error after the commad sudo apt-get update on Ubuntu 16.04 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244349/)

Comment: As of now your question is unclear. Please [edit] your question and paste the output of `sudo apt update` since we don't know which "repository" has issues. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? What do you mean by silver circle icon? In the last sentence you've mentioned ***Which now means I get this, when I try a dist upgrade from 16 to 18, via the Software Updater tool***, what do you mean by "this"?

Comment: in addition to the suggestion from @Kulfy , you might also want to check your list of sources by entering `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` into a terminal and inspecting the uncommented lines (without preceding `#`).  Your sources should correspond to the version of Ubuntu you are using.  (Ex. xenial=16.04).  If you have any non-canonical or non-ubuntu sources, or if there are syntax errors in this file, it can cause problems with updates.

Comment: @Kulfy question has now been edited, TQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently running version 16.10 (*Yakkety Yak*) which is a **standard release** that reached **end of life** in July 2017.  Standard releases come out every 6 months and have a fast upgrade cycle: they are only supported for 9 months.  It is expected for users on this upgrade cycle to upgrade within 3 months of a new release.

By comparison, LTS (long term support) releases, like 16.04.6 (*Xenial Xerus*), are released every two years and are supported for *at least* 5 years.

See [Releases - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for a complete list of releases and support dates.

The reason you are getting errors from `apt` because `apt` is attempting to get updated packages for *Yakkety Yak*, but most mirrors are no longer hosting anything for that version of Ubuntu. Instead all package information has been moved to [Old Releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/).

You should still be able to upgrade your current installation by using a live CD or [bootable USB image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb) of the version you want to upgrade to. There should be an option to [upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu#110483) during installation on the "*Allocate drive space*" prompt.

As of this answer, the most recent standard release is 19.04 and will be supported until January 2020. The most recent LTS release is 18.04.2 which will receive support until April 2023, and extended security maintenance (ESM) from Canonical for an additional five years to 2028.

Comment: ***There should be an option to upgrade:*** AFAIK this option isn't available anymore.

Comment: @Kulfy and NMath... thank you so much. 

Your time and advice have saved our lab $2.5 mil.