# Hard disk partition problem

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Yesterday I have used partition tool in Windows for extending my C drive. After a few hours, my Windows OS is not identified and cannot boot the device. I used live-USB Ubuntu to look into the harddisk files. It shown my partitions as sda1, sda2, sda5 and I moved my files in C drive to other partition.

Today when I planned to format and install Ubuntu or windows using USB, my hard disk is shown in single partitions.

I want to install Ubuntu without damaging my data and partitions.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Which partition is your “C drive”? Where did you move the files from it? What does it mean “showed in single partitions”? Please [edit] your post to explain. Also add the output of the command `LC_ALL=C sudo parted -l`. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text.

Answer (score 1):

### It's backup time!

If you don't want to lose any of your data, **stop trying to boot or change Windows** and boot an [Ubuntu live USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb) in <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd> mode and copy all of the data onto an *external HDD*. (you'll find all of your Windows disks can be mounted from said USB stick) and then:

1. Install Windows again (off-topic here, but on-topic [there](https://superuser.com) )
2. [Install Ubuntu in dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)
3. Restore your data from the external HDD
4. **Start making regular backups!**
   (You came close to losing everything today, protect yourself in the future!)