# boot problem to xubuntu on 2nd hdd

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I have a windows 10 on drive c: installed and recently installed xubuntu to drive D: on a separate partition. I never had a boot menu appearing, always had to boot from the bios into the respective partition (win or Linux).

See the boot repair log here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5vT3S52QpW/

Now I cannot boot xubuntu. The message appears: `System Problem detected, report?` on Ubuntu startup from USB Stick.

What goes wrong here? I am really not a Linux expert...

Comment: You show both drives as gpt for UEFI installs. But your sda2, says ESP, but does not seem to show format. It needs to be FAT32 for Ubiquity installer or Boot-Repair to install grub into it. And you need to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode adding Boot-Repair, so repairs will be in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: Some UEFI have to have allow boot USB or similar setting to boot in UEFI mode from live installer on USB flash drive. Some installers to flash drive make either BIOS or UEFI installer, but ISO is designed to be extracted and booted in either mode if correct tools or settings are used to create live installer.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb & https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb

Answer (score 0):

thank you for responding. the problem: I can not boot to the xubuntu live system on USB other than enabling legacy mode in bios (uefi), because the stick is not showing up in the boot menu of bios. secure boot, fast boot are deselected in this mode..

Comment: if I boot in uefi mode/ secure boot the only boot option is the windows boot manager, nothing else shows up in my bios.

Comment: so I have to format the xubuntu installation partition in Fat32? can I install xubuntu in that filesystem?

Comment: UEFI install needs a ESP - efi system partition for grub to install into. And / (root) partition as ext4. Optionally you can have /home also as ext4 and larger than /. If only testing and using smaller space better to keep / & /home in one partition. If more knowledgable, you may want partition(s) for data or media and those can be ext4 or if shared with Windows can be NTFS. But Windows fast start up must be off if you want to share NTFS partition.