# How to Make Bootable DVD or USB

Tags: 18.04

My system has been update from 16.04 to 18.04 online when popup message display to upgrade OS 18.04.
Now How to make bootable DVD/USB ?
In startup disk creator application not showing source image (System upgrade).

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb) (See screenshot of Startup disk Creator.)

Answer (score 1):

- In order to make a live drive, {DVD/USB/memory card}, you start from a [downloaded iso file](https://releases.ubuntu.com/).
- You can find [official instructions via this link](https://ubuntu.com/#download).
- **Burn** from the iso file to a DVD disk with for example **`k3b`**. (Do *not* make a data DVD and copy the file to it. 'Burn' means 'raw copy' so that the content of the iso file, several directories and files, will be 'visible', when you look at the DVD disk.)
- **Clone** from the iso file to a USB pendrive or memory card with

  - **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator**,
  - **Disks** (alias `gnome-disks`) or
  - [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

---

- Users who have no Ubuntu yet, but start from Windows can use [**Rufus**](https://rufus.ie) to create a USB boot drive or memory card.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running Ubuntu already:

- Download the desktop image for [Ubuntu 18.04](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/), i.e. `ubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso`
- Prepare a USB which does not have any information you would like to keep, as burning a disk image to the USB drive wipes out previously stored data
- Fire up the Terminal and run the following command to list all devices on your system:

  ```bsh
  $ ls /dev
  /dev/sda /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2
  ```

  Note that you may see different output depending on how your hard drive is partitioned, etc.
- Plug in your USB device and run the command again to see what new device pops up - that would be the device node corresponding to your USB drive:

  ```bsh
  $ ls /dev
  /dev/sda /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdb1
  ```

  So in my case, the device node associated with my USB drive is `/dev/sdb`. **Note that your case may be different, so adapt accordingly**.
- Now make sure your USB drive is unmounted, by selecting the USB icon in the GUI if present and clicking "Eject" or similar, but do *not* remove the USB drive.
- After you have confirmed that `/dev/sdb` (in my example, adapt accordingly based on your situation) refers to your USB drive, run:

  ```bsh
  $ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M # Wipe the USB drive
  $ sudo dd if=/path/to/your/ubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M # Burn ISO to USB drive
  ```

  Replace `/path/to/your/ubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso` with the actual path to your disk image, and `/dev/sdb` with the actual device node associated with your USB. **Do not run the above commands until you are 100% certain that `/dev/sdb` (or similar) refers to your USB drive, as selecting the wrong device can wipe your hard drive.**
- Once the above command executes to completion, you may remove your USB drive which is now a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu 18.04. Enjoy :-)