# Installing Ubuntu on SuperMicro

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have a SuperMicro [10024470] Supermicro SYS-5028D-TN4T Mini-
Tower Embedded Intel Processor Barebone and Supermicro MEM-DR432L-CL03-ER26
Memory 32GB DDR4 2666MHz RDIMM AND Supermicro (Seagate) 16TB 3.5.

My problem is that IT didn't come w/any software(Operating System).  My question is the following:

- How do I go about installing Ubuntu
- How do I go about getting RUFUS software to make a bootable USB drive & us the OS image file
  Any assistance would bee greatly appreciated.

Comment: On Ubuntu you can use "startup disk creator"  ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb ) to copy an ISO to an USB. Rufus I assume is windows software. You need to ask windows users on how to use that software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create the installer USB.

   - See our tutorial at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows.
   - The tutorial is for an Ubuntu Desktop installer. If you are building a Server, then simply substitute an Ubuntu Server .iso instead. The process of making the USB installer is identical for both.
2. Boot from the installer USB that you created.

   - Follow the prompts.
   - Stick to the default settings for an easy, fast first install. The default settings are reasonable for the vast majority of users. That's one reason Ubuntu is popular.
   - If something goes wrong, or you don't like the results, then simply reboot and re-install.
3. Boot into your installed system.

Comment: Thank you for the clear & detailed instructions; very much appreciated!!!