# Can I install a distribution from one partition to another using dd?

Tags: system-installation, dd

If I'll do `dd if=isofile.iso of=/dev/sda2` will it work? I need to install a system from iso to the other partition with no use of external drives (from sda1 to sda2 for example).

Comment: That will make the SDA2 usable for installing to a different partition; the copy on sda2 will not be installed but installation copy of the ISO that can be used to later install elsewhere.

Comment: @guiverc will this iso (written on sda2) be listed during boot?

Comment: No...  I've done what you describe, and I modified my existing Grub menu to allow me to boot on my system (*that had no working USB ports*) so I was offered the choice to boot the ISO-on-partition.   FYI:  You can do the same & just boot the ISO from an existing file on partition too which would be what I'd do today,  as using a whole partition instead of just a file makes little sense to me these days with larger disks (it made sense when disks where measured in MB not GB/TB)

Comment: If your computer boots UEFI, you can just extract the ISO to a new, (8GB), FAT32 or NTFS partition and it should boot as Live OS.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1442054/43926

Answer (score 1):

It will do *something*, but it won't do what you want.

`dd` is not an installer. It's simply a copy machine.

Copying an installer simply makes another installer.