# Which program on XP can I use to open the Lubuntu image I've downloaded?

Tags: system-installation

I want rid of XP and as my laptop is 7 years old I thought Lubuntu would fit the bill. I've downloaded it but I can't find a program on XP to open it.

Comment: Some answers at [How to burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/62518) cover Windows. For writing the ISO image to a USB flash drive, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/26269), [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/87165), [that](https://askubuntu.com/q/287064) or [the official instructions](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). It's the same for Lubuntu as the regular Ubuntu images. See also [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328). [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/1366) and [that](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded an .iso file, which is a disk image containing all the Ubuntu files you need that can be burned to either a DVD or a USB, and installed off of those mediums. You do not simply open it to install.

I would suggest reading about installing on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You need to burn the ISO to a CD/DVD, or you can create a bootable USB flash drive.  Depending on how old your system is, you may or may not be able to boot from USB.  Check you BIOS settings to determine if booting from USB is available.

To burn a CD/DVD using XP, you can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/).  Its a free utility that allows you to create a bootable CD/DVD from the ISO.

[image]

If your system can boot from USB, then you can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable USB flash drive.

[image]

Either way you choose, once done, you need to set you BIOS to boot from either methods, to start the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a program to put the installer on USB at [www.pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) then just boot from usb and install.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a disk burner or usb writer program, to write the OS to a storage medium, you then boot your computer from that storage medium to install. Try using pendrivelinux from http://www.pendrivelinux.com to write it to a usb, or nero burning rom from http://www.nero.com/eng/ to write it to a CD :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Wubi installer is always the best choice for testing and making sure everything goes fine before getting rid of your current OS as you will always be able undo the installation anytime and try something else leaving your working OS intact (Windows XP in your case).

Then after making sure everything works fine and stable, you can wipe your entire HDD or whatever decision you take thereafter.

For more details on WUBI installer and detailed procedure have a look to the following link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Note: as you mentioned that your laptop is quite old, I would recommend doing a disk defragmentation to your hard drive before start doing anything ( you can find the how to in **Improving Hard Disk Performance** inside thepreviously mentioned link.

Also, you don't have to redownload the ISO file you got for Lubuntu. Just save the WUBI installer in the same folder and start it, then choose Lubuntu from the list.

Have fun, and enjoy your installation.