# Running Ubuntu from a CD doesn't work for me

Tags: installation, boot, windows, cd

I have tried running the CD with the iso of Linux, but nothing happens and I get back to Windows 8. Is there something I am doing wrong? I press F12 when the prompt appears, and I choose to run from CD drive, and nothing happens.

Comment: Look at my [Answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300377/which-prog-on-xp-to-open-lubuntu-download/300394#300394) it might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some problem burning to the CD. Best is use a flash drive and make it bootable using [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

Comment: Where do you think I should get universal usb installer?

Comment: www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/‎

Comment: that's nice @Mitch

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot your windows CD at startup to be sure it is no issue with your drive or the bios settings.

The next step could be to check the integrity of your .iso file you used to burn the CD, the best way is to compare the md5sum of your .iso and the file should have. Google for MD5 or something similar for windows.

One try would be to choose to boot from your CD in the bios session, some bios versions allow you to choose and run from a device immediately.

The last thing i have on mind is a BIOS, UEFI und Secure Boot issue. If you have the possibility to change to from UEFI to BIOS boot, maybe also called legacy boot.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you burned a copy of the iso  to the CD as a single file, rather than as a a copy of the original CD containing hundreds of separate files with the diretory structure and boot sector you need to have it boot.

If you're stuck on using a CD (I prefer a flash drive) you need a Windows program that will recreate the original CD from the iso.

If you're willing to use a flash drive, try [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).