# Can I download Ubuntu onto a flash drive using Windows xp? It doesn't recognize the ISO file

Tags: usb-drive, windows-xp

For some reason the universal USB installer from pendrivelinux.com does not recognize the ISO file I downloaded. I am wondering if maybe it is because I am using Windows xp. It seems like all the tutorials are using Windows 7.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at my [Answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300377/which-prog-on-xp-to-open-lubuntu-download/300394#300394), and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That should not be the problem. You should maybe check your .iso file for errors. Does the filesize match the one given on the website. Maybe check the [md5 value](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) of the file. Maybe try another USB Installer. [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

1- place both ISO file and Universal USB installer in the same folder.
2- Download the latest version.
3- You have to select the same release/version/architecture from the list that matches your downloaded ISO file (for example, selecting **ubuntu 13.10 Desktop amd64** from the list will not identify **Ubuntu-12.04-Desktop-amd64.ISO** you have to be accurate and select the match for your ISO.