# Installation of ubuntu from USB flash drive

Tags: usb

I have gone through the online instructions for installing Ubuntu from a USB flash drive.

So it says first that I have to download Ubuntu in order to install it from flash drive.

So I downloaded the software. It is a file of type `.iso`.  So what do I do with this `.iso` file? How to prepare my USB flash drive so that I reboot and install the Ubuntu?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What operating system are you currently using? If it's Windows, you'll need a utility to recreate the original Ubuntu installation disk from the .iso file you downloaded. I haven't owned a machine running Windows in ten years, so I can't help you with this. You can recreate the Ubuntu install on a DVD or on a USB drive, as you think best, but you can't really do anything with the file as it is. Simply copying the .iso file to a DVD or flash drive will not work. Then you change your boot order to boot from the DVD or USB. If you want to dual-boot, look into that before you begin installing.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu The OP wants to install Ubuntu from USB, and not XP.  So it can't be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a bootable USB from Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87165/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-from-windows) or [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Answer (score 1):

You've completed step one, which is to download Ubuntu.

Step two would be to "prepare" the USB flash drive with that `.iso` file. We call this "creating a bootable USB flash drive". If you are on Windows right now, here's what you need to do:

1. [Download the Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).
2. Open up the program, and select your Ubuntu version from the drop-down list. So, for example, if you've downloaded the 32-bit Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop, choose Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop i386.

   [image]
3. Using the "Browse" button, point to your downloaded `.iso` file.

   [image]
4. Choose your USB flash drive from the drop-down list.

   > **Note:** make sure you are choosing the correct USB flash drive and that you have a backup of whatever is on it, because the program will most likely delete everything on it.

   [image]

Once you are finished with that program, you can now use your USB flash drive to install Ubuntu. So switch off your computer, plug the USB flash drive into it, and turn on the computer. Depending on the settings of your computer, you should see a purple screen within a minute, which is the beginning of the Ubuntu installation. If you don't see a purple screen and your computer boots directly into Windows, you will need to change the settings of your computer to basically tell it to boot from the USB. To do that, you will need to press a specific button when your computer is first powering on. This button is different for different computers, but it's usually one of the function buttons (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>).

I don't know what guide you're following to install Ubuntu, but you can follow the screenshots [**in this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/52726) for the Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to install it from the flash drive do the following:

**In Windows**

Download [Lili](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/downloads/?stable) 
Use Lili to write the .iso file into flash drive.[Documentation](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide/preparation) is available in the lili website

**In Linux**
Download Unetbootin and again you can write the ubuntu .iso file into flashdrive using this software

Comment: Another great windows tool is rufus ( http://rufus.akeo.ie/ )