# Bootable USB gets grub error

Tags: live-usb, grubrescue

I connected a live USB stick on startup and this happened:

### welcome to GRUB

->error: filesystem unknown
->Entering rescue mode
-> ls
->(hd0) (hd1) (hd2)
-> ls (hd0,msdos0)
-error: no such partition
-(hd0): Filesystem unknown
-> ls (hd0)
-(hd0): Filesystem unknown
-**NB**
1.I run windows7(64bit)
2.i didn't have dual boot
3.If I dont connect the live usb my PC starts on windows7 just fine.

Comment: How did you create the USB? https://askubuntu.com/questions/87165/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-from-windows

Comment: I downloaded an iso image and used Rufus to create a live usb

Comment: Please check with **md5sum** that the iso file was downloaded correctly. See  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes -- I think Rufus can calculate and show the md5sum.

Comment: I checked it and it matched with md5 and sha1

Comment: Rufus has a good reputation. What is the name of the iso file, and from where did you download it? And what computer are you running? Brand name, model, RAM (size), graphics chip/card, wifi chip/card?

Comment: I downloaded Manjaro KDE, my mainboard is Gigabyte b250, RAM-8GB, Processor-Core i3, no external card

Comment: At AskUbuntu we can help you with issues about Ubuntu and Ubuntu family flavours for example Kubuntu, with KDE. So if you download a Kubuntu iso file and use Rufus to make your USB drive bootable, we can help you. You can probably get better help for Manjaro at a Manjaro forum.

Comment: I would try again or try unetbootin.not saying that rufus is the problem, maybe you are setting an option that you shouldn't and trying a different way to create the usb will solve it.