# How to install Ubuntu using a USB stick?

Tags: installation, boot, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive)

I cannot install Ubuntu 11.10 from a USB stick. It doesn't boot to Ubuntu page for installation but remains on Windows 7.

I've downloaded the 11.10 version iso file and burnt it to a USB stick. After I inserted it, the USB stick is a symbol of Ubuntu installation and I clicked wubi to try to install it. But it didn't boot to Ubuntu but stayed on Win 7 after restart. It occurred error and said "windowsBackend" object has no attribut "cd_path" when I chose "Help me to boot from CD". I thought it's the problem of my computer model (acer travelmate 8481), but it can't boot on an old computer using XP as well.

How can I solve this problem and install Ubuntu to replace Windows?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive