# Program to install Ubuntu from a USB?

Tags: installation, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive)

I want to install Ubuntu in my computer from USB (With out copy ubuntu iso to a DVD) because in my EEEpc i haven´t DVD.

What program could i use and what are the steps to do it?