# Clean Install of ubuntu from flash drive

Tags: installation, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive)

Can I install Ubuntu to a newly formatted h/d from the flash drive?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you aren't on an older computer which does not support booting from USB flash drives, then yes, you can install Ubuntu from a USB flash drive. You can also use a CD-ROM, DVD, or PXE boot (if on a network with a PXE server), if your computer supports them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can and the how to make Live USB process is here  .

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu