# Can I permanently install from a flash drive?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive)

Is it possible to permanatly intsall ubuntu on my hard drive using the usb flash drive method. I installed the os on my flash drive and booted, everything works fine, but i want it to stay there without the use of the flash. Im working on an acer aspire one netbook and its the only why i could get a working os on it without an external cd. any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible.Do you try to install Ubuntu in to your hard drive.I do it from flash drive.It works.