# Trying to boot Ubuntu from USB - Only getting FreeDOS command prompt

Tags: installation, usb, live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)

I own a little Acer Aspire One with no CD drive (it's a 10' notebook and was given it with operating system / AVG failure and wont boot windows). So I thought I'd put Linux on it. I have a CD with i386 - 32bit (as it is compatible with MOST things) which I've had running on a HP notebook of a friend's. I have created an ISO with IMGburn and created a boot-able thumb drive (4 GB Imation) with Rufus.

When I boot from USB, I am asked for a keyboard layout - no worries and then I get a command prompt (FeeDOS DISPLAY version 0.013). Once I managed to get a very basic help screen, that got me nowhere of use.

The only thing I can get it to do is tell it a:>drive which it chucks a hissy fit as this is not the USB drive and it is stuck at that. Wondering what I've got wrong?

I should add that I've done this using the image of Ubuntu 12.04 i386 Live CD if any of this makes a difference. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because you created a DOS boot disk with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/), but you need to create media that just boots the Live CD or alternate installer, which is different. Please follow the c[ommunity documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).

Answer (score 0):

In your question you have not mentioned the bios settings . the problem might be 1st priority .

look at your BIOS settings and put the 1st boot priority as Removal disk and 2nd as Hard disk then boot again . I am sure it will boot to your USB and will give you a Ubuntu live System , unless you made some mistakes while making a bootable USB .

for more information on how to make a bootable USB Ubuntu Live CD , please refer this .
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: The BIOS is set to load USB first. It loads the USB and shows FreeDOS, and if I ask for C:\>dir it shows me the 5 or 6 files on the USB stick:
As follows:
FreeCom version 0.84-pre2 XMS_swap
etc, etc about FreeDOS
Volume in drive C is INSTALL UBU
LOCALE                       <DIR>
CONFIG           SYS          277
AUTOEXEC         BAT          210
AUTORUN          INF          224