# How Do I Install From A Live USB?

Tags: installation, usb, live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)

I remember doing this from a while ago but I had to uninstall Ubuntu for....
capacity reasons. Now, could someone guide me?
I'm using a 64-bit Windows 7 Intel Core i5 and I want to install 12.04 LTS.
Also if anyone suggests I modify my BIOS settings, help me with this too.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. What is actually you want to do?

Comment: I believe the Install Ubuntu option on the Live session will Install Ubuntu.

Comment: Uzumaki, I am trying to install Ubuntu from a Live USB. I can find a WUBI in the USB after making it a Live USB. I recall doing this from a few months ago but I do not remember anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have a Live USB already , if not you have to create it .

1. get [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button) software , for creating Live USB from windows .

2.follow these steps

Select Ubuntu Desktop Edition from the dropdown list.
[image]

[image]

click at browse and select your ISO file .Then click at create .this will create a live USB for you from windows .

for this part credit goes here :[Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Now we have to configure the BIOS settings as Removal disk should be as 1st boot priority and HDD as 2nd . Now connect your USB and your PC will boot and take you to installation process .

After Ubuntu loading , you will get like this [image] , choose   Install Ubuntu .Then it will directs you to Preparing to install Ubuntu where it will check about minimum requirement . Internet connection doesn't matter but you should have minimum empty space as its mentioned .Then click at continue.Then next step is allocate drive step ,look at the image .[image] , here you have to choose what kind of install you want to give . each type have its clear description , so you can easily understand . there partitioning you have to mention . make sure that you have selected an empty partition for Ubuntu install or a partition which you dont want .
[image]
[image]

you have to select the partition and you have to select it as EXT4/EXT3 and then mount point as / then click at create . Size is your wish but make sure about the minimum size (> 5 GB) .Creating swap is a good move .

more information on swap will be here : [swapfaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq).

Remaining steps are something like keyboard layout,languages and times Zones . I hope you can handle them safely .

Credit goes to :[techspot.com](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/) [softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Installing-Ubuntu-12-04-LTS-266201.shtml)