# Creating a USB installer

Tags: installation, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)

I know I can install ubuntu on a USB thumb-drive, but is it possible to use a USB thumb drive as a replacement for dvd installation disk?

Edit:
I don't have an empty DVD, and that's why I need it.

Answer (score 3):

If you install Ubuntu on a USB thumb-drive (using Startup Disk Creator), when you re-boot with the stick plugged in, you'll have the option to install just as you would with a DVD Installation Disk.  Nb: You may have to change your BIOS settings to ensure your system boots to the USB before the hard drive, but after that, you should have smooth sailing. See your Motherboard/BIOS documentation on how to check the boot order.