# No cd Rom. No installation?

Tags: usb, live-usb, cd

## I do not have a cd rom on my netbook.

It is an aspire one and I cannot install ubuntu due to be not having a cd rom.
Can i use usb ports? And how to i make a "live" usb drive?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/26269/44179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the very detailed instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).