# Can I install Ubuntu with a new blank Hard Drive?

Tags: installation, usb, windows-7, hard-drive, microsoft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)

I am planning to install a new blank hard drive on my computer but i cannot find the windows iso file i need(windows 7 starter) so can i just install ubuntu instead when i put the new hard drive in? i dont have a cd/dvd rom reader on my laptop. i can only install from usb stick.
and no windows 7 starter's iso file cannot be found ANYWHERE! windows 7 starter is only preinstalled in computers, and yes i already contacted microsoft and they disagreed to give me it.