# Difference between alternate and desktop 64 bit? and how do i find out which one i am using now?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, grubrescue

My system has crashed because of deleting a partition that i should not have deleted. Now i want to create a liveusb but i am confused whether i should make the liveusb with the alternate of desktop version of the 64bit ubuntu... (i am now stuck in the grub rescue,

1- How do i find out which one i used install my current ubuntu?
2- If i need to make a liveusb with the 64 bit desktop version of ubuntu. What software can i use to make the usb? The program that was suggested in the topic 'boot rescue' only allows to create an alternate 64 bit not a desktop one...

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is using the alternate it wouldn't be a "live" usb, alternate is an image that installs without booting a "live" Ubuntu.

The download for the .iso should include -alternate in the name, example: **ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso**

I suggest using the regular download because of issues with booting the alternate on usb.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

For help creating a live usb this question may help: [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)