# Writing ISO to USB

Tags: server

I downloaded the iso for ubuntu-12.04.2-server, the PC I'm installing this on does not have a cd or dvd drive.  I'd like to write this to a flash drive, all the utilities i would normally use are only good for windows, how can I do this for Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick?](http://askubuntu.com/q/26269/8698)