# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop amd64 using bootable USB-stick failed

Tags: installation

I created a bootable USB-Stick using the Pendrive Universal USB Installer as suggested on the Ubuntu website, because I want to install Ubuntu 13.04 Desktob amd64. When I turned on my PC with the USB-stick inserted, it found it, but told me this:

SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H: Peter Anvin et al
ERROR: No configuration file found
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found
boot:

My PC is an Acer Travelmate with 4 GB RAM and currently a 64bit System.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is and what I can do to make it work? (I'm a total newcomer to Ubuntu)

Thanks!

Comment: try using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: take a look at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick) and tell us your results with the methods mentioned there.

Comment: I tried both unetbootin and LiLi even using another pandrive additionnally, but to no avail. With unetbootin the PC at least tried to boot, but then wrote: Invalid or corrupt kernel image

Comment: have you verified your download was good? check the md5sum

Comment: what exactly is that and how do I check it?

Answer (score -1):

I finally resolved the problem like this (but couldn't get my internet working rightaway, hence the late answer):

I formatted my USB-Stick to FAT32, then used unetbootin to create a bootable USB-Stick.
My computer detected it, there appeared a list with several options (Try Ubuntu; Install Ubuntu now; etc.) but the automatic boot failed, with the same error appearing as before:

Invalid or corrupt kernel image

boot:

I did it another time and instead of allowing it to boot automatically, I selected "Install Ubuntu now". This worked out fine and there was no complaint about an invalid or corrupt kernel image. (I don't understand totally what the kernel image is, but a friend, who has Ubuntu himself, told me, as long as Ubuntu works now, the error-message from before doesn't matter.)

Thanks for all the help!