# Can't install from USB - "missing operating system"

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I have tried to reinstall Ubuntu after forgetting my admin password. I have downloaded Ubuntu, but it comes up with missing operating system when I connect the USB onto which I have downloaded and unpacked the operating system.

What am I doing wrong? I managed to go into shell and try and change the password there. It says it was successful but when trying to download something it says the password is wrong. This is the reason I would like to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB?

Comment: `I have tried to reinstall Ubuntu after forgetting my admin password.` You didn't have to do that. http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: Which version do You use? Please edit this question including version tag.

Answer (score 0):

You will never succeed to boot from the USB in the way you said you put ubuntu on it ("I have downloaded and unpacked the operating system onto"). Follow these instructions to manage this: [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)