# I can't boot from USB stick

Tags: installation, boot, usb

I copied the ISO file and tried to boot from USB to install Ubuntu 13.04. Didn't work :(
then tried after all the files in the ISO image copied to the USB stick. Also didn't work
"Missing operation system" was the message
I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside of Windows Vista and I've removed it.
Thank you

Comment: Have you copied if manually or used unetbootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/? If you did this by yourself you need to install a bootloader.

Comment: You don't get to just copy the files or the ISO file to the flash drive. See the question above, http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick

Answer (score 0):

You tried to create the bootable usb with universal application like usb-installer?

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Answer (score 0):

To make a USB stick to a boost device.It should be use tools make it a bootable device.
For example ISO file, you could use linux command

```
dd if=**.iso of=/dev/sdb BS=1M
```

**.iso is the system image

/dev/sdb is the usb device