# I downloaded Ubuntu. it appeared as a removable disk drive. Then i restarted my computer. The ubuntu files were missing. How do I get them back?

Tags: installation, 12.10, restart

After I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 on to my laptop running windows 8, it appeared as a removable disk drive (DVD Drive).

I then clicked on the wubi application, but it did not respond, so I restarted my computer.

After I restarted and opened my computer the Ubuntu files are missing. I couldn't search for them either.

My laptop- Sony SVF5212.

- Is Ubuntu still there?
- How can I install now?

Comment: Please just **don't use Wubi**. It is depreciated. Also, use Ubuntu 13.04 or 12.04 LTS. Check how to create a Installation Media [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)

Answer (score 0):

It should still be there (assuming you did not delete it). Burn the .iso file to a CD or DVD using a burning tool of your choice and then put the burned disk into your drive and restart your computer.

It should boot into the LiveCD and if it doesn't, restart your computer again and press ESC or F12 to open a boot menu. Select your Disk Drive and boot to it.

Once booted you should be able to install Ubuntu.

Have a good one.