# Using a flash drive to boot up ubuntu

Tags: installation

I would like to know if it is possible to put ubuntu on a flashdrive and bootup from that instead of burning a disc?
Thanks

Comment: Follow the link from guntbert's comment above. In addition, whenever you like to read some more, follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick) and [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

*(Use at your own risk!)*

Yes, it is possible to write the Ubuntu Live DVD image onto a flash drive, and it is easy as long as you don't want to boot it in UEFI mode but in standard BIOS mode.

## Using UNetbootin

A user-friendly solution is [**UNetbootin**](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), which works on Windows, Linux and MacOS and provides a graphical user interface which even downloads the Ubuntu image for you and writes it directly onto your flash drive:

[image: Screenshot of UNetbootin]

## Using command line `dd`

If you're running Linux or OS X, you can `dd` the Ubuntu image onto your flash drive:

```
$ sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu-iso-image of=/dev/sdx
```

where `/dev/sdx` is the your flash drive. On Linux, you can use `sudo blkid` to find out the device path, if you have only one hard drive connected, this *could* be `/dev/sdb`, but please be careful, as `dd` is going to delete all data on the device specified after `of=`.

A port of `dd` is also [available for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd).