# Help please? Downloaded ubuntu 13.04 onto usb and can't find .iso file in order to create a bootable usb

Tags: installation, 13.04, boot, live-usb, iso

I asked a question which was immediately merged with this question: [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick) .

I can understand most of what is said there, except that when I try and use http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ to create a bootable usb (i want to create one with a laptop which has no cd drive so i can install in on my pc with new blank harddrive), I can't find the .iso file. I downloaded ubuntu 13.04 desktop onto my usb and extracted all the files. So when I am on that universal usb installer i am browsing for .iso files among the ubuntu 13.04 files i downloaded but just can't find one!

To be honest I am a beginner and barely know what a .iso file is so please bear with me, be amused and help me not go back to windows!