# How to Install Dual boot ubuntu and win8 on Asus F202E-CT148H?

Tags: dual-boot

I purchased Asus F202E-CT148H VivoBook with no Optical drive and it has 4 factory installed partitions with Win 8 preloaded.
I want to install Ubuntu 13.04 on it but I am not able to do so as it ts coming with pre-installed windows 8 and UEFI  , Secure boot. 
I tried all possible way mentioned on youtube and ubuntu forum. With USB also its not booting after disabling secure boot, fast boot.
So any one installed dual boot win8 & ubuntu on Asus F202E-CT148H, Plz help. ?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried this? - [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835) & also this [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/26269)

Answer (score 0):

You must first disable UEFI on your computer BIOS, once you have done that Windows will still be able to start. You will then enter boot options and set to boot from the USB you have created of the Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit iso (you can use Universal USB installer on Windows to do this) and you will then be able to install it.

PS: You can also from Windows mount the iso you have downloaded by double clicking on it and install Wubi.exe that will install Ubuntu inside your Windows partition :)

Comment: i think wibi is not working anymore atleat on win8

Comment: @user233154 how did you access bios?

Comment: I followed these steps to go to BIOS 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported