# How to download Ubuntu on a USB stick and install it alongside Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, downloads, usb-creator

How do I download Ubuntu onto a USB stick? And can I then install alongside Windows 7? Or is it better to boot from the USB.

Comment: See also [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/22949) and [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/26269/22949) In short, booting from USB and installing alongside Windows 7 are not mutually exclusive. Booting from USB is even one of the most common ways to install Ubuntu (alongside Windows 7 or otherwise) and doing so will let you test the system before installing it (though it will work a bit differently once installed).

Answer (score 0):

Please atleast try Google first

[Install Ubuntu alongside Windows](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

I know it says Windows 8.1 and you have 7 but just ignore the first step and adjust accordingly

You ca use it from USB but it is MUCH (proberly about 20 times) slower to read/write a USB VS a HDD, try both see what suits you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.