# connecting to a wireless network BCM 4318 Rev 2

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have recently downloaded **Ubuntu** 10.10 to replace **Windows XP** on our family laptop. I have accomplished a sound OS with one exception. The laptop will not detect a wireless network. before reformatting everything was fine and network works on all other devices.

I have spent countless hours going over other similar threads with no results. This leads me to believe I am doing something wrong or I have a unique situation here.

I believe I have a Broadcom series of PCI card. Reading and following **Chili555**'s thread (to no result) I get the following info:

```
~$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
05:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
```

.. which tells me I have a **BCM 4318 Rev 2**, but I find that 'rev' not listed. I also have tried to upgrade to 14.14 but I am unsure if this has been accomplished.

*If any of this make sense to anyone please let me know.*

Comment: You should be attempting to install/use Ubuntu **12.04 LTS** or **14.04 LTS** (32-bit), and not an outdated version. Trying to *upgrade* from **10.10** is also not likely to succeed.

Comment: I have tried downloading 14.04 LTs both by open with (default) and save as file then installing to no result. why isn't it running automatically? I have also tried to manually install as file... Any hint as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't upgraded to 14.04 or 14.10, please do so as Ubuntu 10.10 reached its end-of-life on April 10, 2012; that means that crucial security updates are no longer available. Find out from the terminal with:

```
lsb_release -d
```

Once you have 14.04 or later installed, please do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If the terminal reports that it isn't installed, that's fine, just proceed.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and tell us if your wireless is now woking.

Comment: upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 and followed Chili555 steps... connects perfectly... thanks so much!

Comment: Chili I cannot find a tab or a link to accept???

Comment: @JasonB Do you see the star below the arrows? I believe you click that: http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: The only thing it will allow me to do is accept the answer as it says I do not have enough "reputation to vote up". thanks again...

Comment: You got it accepted. Thanks. Glad it's working!