# Problem in booting with USB stick to install Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS .iso file and created a bootable USB stick using UUI. When I tried using it on my HP pavilion laptop, I am not able to make the laptop boot from USB. Am not able to figure out how to change the boot order. I want to install Ubuntu on a separate partition and want to retain windows 8 as well. Step-by-Step instructions required please. Even with boot priority set to USB, the system does not find the operating system(Ubuntu) to start loading. I tried CD/DVD boot too. This is the msg. which is displayed.
[image: Boot display] This is how my boot options in BIOS looks like: [image: BIOS Boot Options] Any solutions welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

1. When turning on your machine boot to your BIOS settings by pressing the key F2, or other F[number] if you have different machine settings.
2. Use right arrow key to move to the "BOOT" menu right on the top of your screen, the you will see a list of Boot inputs (DVD Drive, USB, Disk Drive, or whatever), I think you will find your Disk Drive on top of the list because the logic of boot of the computer says "I search for boot sector in number1 of the list, if found I Load that system else I move to the next in the list if found I load that system else I move to the next and so on until it finishes all the Boot inputs (the boot list)".
3. So you want to see "USB Drive" on top of the list, look down the screen and read how you can change that list, usually I do this by putting the cursor on what ever I want to be on top of the list the I press (+) button to move it the top, press it few times until it's number 1 in the list.
4. If you are done, don't forget to save changes either by pressing exit then when it asks you for save say "yes" or search for save option and do it.
5. Now, you are ready to Boot from you USB, put it there and turn on your machine and it will work.

If this is a little difficult to follow, here is a video that describes how it works maybe it can make things lot easier with video: [your link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIF8e_5F9B4).
Your issue will start on 5:20 so be tuned.

Comment: I have been trying exactly the same thing as above but with no success. It does not find the operating system in the USB stick and goes on to load the windows 8 in my hard disk. Nothing happens even after setting the boot priority to USB first. That is my problem

Comment: So, are you sure that the USB is bootable?
if all the steps are done correctly, and  the PC jump to the next BOOT input (Hard disk) this means that it asked the USB do you have boot? and where is it? the USB says NO (maybe only data of the OS).

This is my logic, so try to boot with CD or DVD if it does work, than you should create a bootable USB or verify the  one you use now.

Comment: I have added screen shots of my problem. Kindly review and reply.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Windows 8 or later the boot sequence is secure and will not let you boot to anything but Windows. You will have to disable secure booting to be able to boot to a live cd or usb.

Comment: Secure Boot _is_ disabled. It says it right in the picture.